# Bypass windows security password when importing pfx file

Tags: powershell

After importing pfx file windows security is asking for a password to protect the pfx file.

I'm trying to do a invoke-restmethod by passing the pfx file calling directly from the personal certificate store but it prompts me for the same password at the end. I get the expected result but I want to bypass the credential or pass that pw with my query since I want to automate the process. Any help is appreciated. Below is my code.

$cert = Get-childitem Cert:\CurrentUser\My<Thumbprint>

Invoke-restmethod -method get -uri  -Certificate $cert

Note: The password that gets prompted is not the same as the one that is tied to the file but it's prompted by windows security.

Comment: Please specify, do you need to import pfx or execute invoke-restmethod?

Comment: Yes. The pfx is needed to make the rest call to communicate with the client.